# Cakephp multiple handlers per event dispatch

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to run two handlers on an event in cakephp. I want to return data from the listener to the class that called it to be saved, like in the cake docs. I tried their example but I'm having these two problems: 1) I can only seem to get one of the events to fire and 2) I can't figure out how to pass data between the methods using $event->result and back to my model to save.

Here is my code: (Case is somewhat made up, but illustrates the problem.)

/app/Model/User.php

```
public function afterSave($created) {
   if ($created) {
         $event = new CakeEvent('Model.User.created', $this, array(
            'id' => $this->id,
            'data' => $this->data[$this->alias],
            'result' => $event->result
        ));
        $this->getEventManager()->dispatch($event);
        if (!empty($event->result)) {
            $this->save($event->result);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

/app/Event/UserListener.php

```
public function implementedEvents() {
    return array(
        'Model.User.created' => 'method1',
        'Model.User.created' => 'method2',
    );
}

public function method1(CakeEvent $event) {
  //do something
  $event->result['User']['role_id'] = 1;
}

public function method2(CakeEvent $event) {
  //do something else
  $event->result['User']['status_id'] = 2;
}
```

When I run this all I get is the result from one of the two methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic php language "problem", it is logical here that...

```
return array(
    'Model.User.created' => 'method1',
    'Model.User.created' => 'method2',
);
```

...the 2nd key is *the same* as the first one so you're overriding the value of the first key. This can't work.

I would recommend to have one method for the event and do something like this:

```
public function method1(CakeEvent $event) {
  $event->result['User']['role_id'] = ClassRegistry::init('User')->doSomethingWithId($event->data);
  $event->result['User']['status_id'] = ClassRegistry::init('User')->doSomethingWithStatus($event->data);
}
```

I would **not** implement the actualy logic that deals with the data inside the event listener but instead put it into a model. Much more easy to test and re-use in other places from there.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I spent about 3 hours experimenting with this. Wow, I feel dumb. Alright, so there really isn't much point to have listener on user create to only call functions in the user model, correct? I could could just call them with `$this->dosomething();`, but it would make sense if model x needed to call methods in models y and z?

Comment: Use whatever model you want, the User model was just an example, I don't know what you want to do at the end of the day. The point why to put it into a model is explained in my answer. But yes, you can can call a method on a class that triggered the event. There is nothing wrong with that but you could also use some of the existing callbacks like beforeSave() afterSave() or beforeFilter() and beforeRender() in the case of a controller.